# Install Powershell Modules in Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Function 2.0 with Powershell and getting below error while installing Powershell modules.

Is there any way to get rid of this error. In general, we don't need admin rights to install NuGet/dependency.

I also tried with another way to put all Powershell modules under Modules folder
[image]

Still, function is not able to find Cosmos DB modules

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot simply call `Import-Module Az.Profile`** like on your local machine where you have previously installed `Az.Profile` from that site. But you have to copy all files from that locally installed package into specific folder inside of your Function App in Azure.

1.Install `Az.Profile` in local and go to its folder to get all the content in it.

2.Go to your function KUDU. Click CMD>site>wwwroot>yourFunctionName then create a directory called `modules`.

3.Simply `drag-and-drop` all files from your local powershell module location to your Azure Function App folder create above(`modules`).

4.Include `Az.Profile` PowerShell module in `run.ps1` file like that example below:

```
Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\modules\Az.Profile.psd1"
```

5.Install `Az.Resources` and `CosmosDB` module as above steps.

6.Run `Get-CosmosDbOffer -Context $cosmosDbContext` and you will get the following snapshot.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://rasper87.wordpress.com/2019/01/25/import-powershell-module-package-into-azure-function/) and this [one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-powershell-modules-in-azure-functions/).

Comment: Are you using Function version 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I use the default version 2.0.

Comment: Yes, it's working. I was copying the complete PowerShell module folder under modules folder

Comment: Copying all .psd1 and .dll files under modules folders maybe create conflict. for now, I'm okay to continue

Answer (score 5):

If the modules you want to use are on the PowerShell Gallery, the easiest way to use them from PowerShell Functions is to take advantage of the [Managed Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management) feature. All you need to do is to make sure you have the feature enabled in the host.json:

```
{
  "managedDependency": {
          "enabled": true
       }
}
```

and your module is mentioned in the requirements.psd1:

```
@{
    Az = '2.*'
    SqlServer = '21.1.18147'
}
```

Azure Functions will automatically make sure these modules are installed and available to your functions. No need to copy files.

Please also note that **AzureRM** modules are not supported on Azure Functions v2.0, use **Az** instead.

Comment: Let me try.. will see if it will solve my purpose. Thanks