# Create azure dynamic group from azure functions powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I am trying to create an azure function that has to create azure dynamic group when i execute the function from MS flow. I am using below code for this purpose.

```
$groupName = $Request.Query.Name
$groupDesc = $Request.Query.Desc
$domainnames = $Request.Query.DomainName
$dynamicrule = ""
Foreach($domainname in $domainnames.Split(";"))
{
   $dynamicrule = $dynamicrule + "(user.userPrincipalName -contains ""_$domainname"") or";
}
$dynamicrule = $dynamicrule -replace ".{2}$"
$dynamicrule = $dynamicrule + "and (user.objectId -ne null)";
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName $groupName -Description $groupDesc -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule $dynamicrule -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

When i execute the above command, i am getting below error messgae.

**ERROR: The term 'New-AzureADMSGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.Exception             :Type        : System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundExceptionErrorRecord**

Can sombody please help me on how can i create dynamic groups using azure function app.

Thanks,
Venu

Comment: Did you install the corresponding PowerShell module?

Comment: I have not install anything as i am doing it in azure function app. If at all i need to install the azure module, may you please guide me on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: See if this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882577/install-powershell-modules-in-azure-function

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, you did not install `AzureAD` powershell module in your function app. And if you want to create a dynamic group, you need to use the `-MembershipRule` parameter, it is just available in the preview version i.e. `AzureADPreview` module. Though the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0#examples) looks like the parameter is available in `AzureAD`, but per my test, it is not available.

[image]

Actually it is easy to solve the issue, but if you want to create a dynamic group with `New-AzureADMSGroup`, there will be a few follow-up issues, you could follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the function app in the portal -> `Identity` -> enable the [system-assigned identity(MSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet) for your app.

2.Navigate to `App files` -> `host.json` -> make sure the `managedDependency` is `Enabled`.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

In the `requirements.psd1`, add the `AzureADPreview` like below, then it will install the `AzureADPreview` module for you automatically.

```
@{
    'Az' = '5.*'
    'AzureADPreview' = '2.0.2.129'
}
```

In the `profile.ps1`, **remove all the things** and add the lines below, this is used to solve the issue related to AzureAD powershell in function, without it, you will get an error,  details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232).

```
$64bitPowerShellPath = Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:Windir\WinSxS -Filter PowerShell.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "amd64"}
$env:64bitPowerShellPath=$64bitPowerShellPath.VersionInfo.FileName
```

3.If you want to use `New-AzureADMSGroup` to create group in Azure AD, you need the permission in Microsoft Graph, in this case, we use MSI to auth, so use the commands below to give the permission to your MSI.

Run the commands below **in local** with the **Global admin** user account, replace `<functionapp-name>`:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '<functionapp-name>'")
$MSGraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$MSGraphAppId'"
$PermissionName = "Group.ReadWrite.All"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
```

4.After step 2, navigate to the kudu(in the `Advanced Tools` blade of the function app) -> `data` -> `ManagedDependencies` -> click the file with the format like `201208083153165.r`(choose the newest one via the Modified time) -> check if the `AzureADPreview` module was installed successfully like below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

5.After the module was installed, in your function code, use the lines below, in my sample, I use this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1--create-a-dynamic-group) to test directly, you could change the code depends on your requirements, remember to replace `201208083153165.r` with yours in step 4, it works fine on my side.

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

if ($name) {
    $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
}

$script = { 
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
$context = Get-AzContext
$graphtoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com").Token
$aadtoken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net").Token
Import-Module D:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\201208083153165.r\AzureADPreview
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $context.Account -TenantId $context.Tenant -MsAccessToken $graphtoken -AadAccessToken $aadtoken
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "joyd1" -Description "Dynamic group created from PS" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
}
&$env:64bitPowerShellPath -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command $Script

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

[image]

Check the group in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Please don't rely on the folder names under ManagedDependencies (such as `201208083153165.r`). All the content under ManagedDependencies is automatically managed by Azure Functions. If you hardcode any name, it may appear to work for some time, but Azure Functions will eventually remove and replace this folder with another one, breaking your code. Here is one way to reliably get the current location of the module: `(Get-Module AzureADPreview -ListAvailable).Path` (run it from the main Function body, not from the scriptblock).