# Azure PowerShell Function fails to run when deployed but works locally

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-durable-functions

Azure PowerShell function works locally in VS Code successfully. However, when deployed to a function and run in Azure portal, it fails with the following error:

```
2023-12-14T21:05:44Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '3e85a40a-a930-78d8-be83-f53bd9847ab1
2023-12-14T21:05:44Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:3e85a40a-a930-78d8-be83-f53bd9847ab1 on workerId:e8588e50-b2ad-4012-bf5b-92df7aa00739
2023-12-14T21:05:44Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing the 'Az.Accounts' module. If 'Az.Accounts' is available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see [here](https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency).
2023-12-14T21:05:44Z   [Error]   ERROR: The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Exception             : 
    Type    : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
    Message : The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    HResult : -2147024894
TargetObject          : Az.Accounts
CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Az.Accounts:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
InvocationInfo        : 
    MyCommand        : Import-Module
    ScriptLineNumber : 9
    OffsetInLine     : 1
    HistoryId        : 1
    ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\Func_Sample_1\run.ps1
    Line             : Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
                       
    PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\Func_Sample_1\run.ps1:9 char:1
                       + Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
                       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\Func_Sample_1
    PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\Func_Sample_1\run.ps1
    InvocationName   : Import-Module
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\Func_Sample_1\run.ps1: line 9
PipelineIterationInfo : 

[... Repeat for 'Az.Resources' and 'SqlServer' ...]
```

## **requirements.psd1:**

```
# See [here](https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency) for additional information.
@{
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.*' 
    'Az.Resources' = '6.*' 
    'SqlServer' = '22.*'
}
```

**# run.ps1:**

```
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Import the necessary modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
Import-Module Az.Resources -Force
Import-Module SqlServer -Force

# Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount
Write-Host "Request database access token for managed identity"
$MI_Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net ).Token
```

Verified that the modules added in requirements.psd1 are available in the PowerShell Gallery. My understanding is that modules should be downloaded automatically if they are available in the PowerShell Gallery. However, it fails in the portal. Tried manually copying the modules into the site wwwroot\Modules folder, but it still didn't help. Running out of ideas on what's missing and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management)?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I followed that article.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ian-kemp for the comment.

If the modules which you need are available on the PowerShell Gallery, you can use them in PowerShell Functions using the Managed Dependencies.

- Enable the **Managed Dependencies** feature in the `host.json` and mention your modules in the `requirements.psd1`.

Azure Functions will make sure these modules are installed and available for the functions.

- Check the available `Powershell` modules with the command `Get-Module -ListAvailable`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

- I have created a PowerShell function and deployed to Azure function App:

```
using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)


# Import the necessary modules
Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
Import-Module Az.Resources -Force
Import-Module SqlServer -Force

# Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount
Write-Host "Request database access token for managed identity"
$MI_Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net ).Token
```

**profile.ps1:**

```
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
```

**requirements.psd1:**

```
@{
'Az'='2.*'
'SqlServer'  =  '22.*'
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**Portal Reponse:**

[image]

**References:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914450/19991670

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into this @Pravallika.

This is what I did following your comments:

1. Created a new function app in the portal
2. **run.ps1**

   ```
            using namespace System.Net
            using namespace System.Data.SqlClient

            param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)


            Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
            Import-Module Az.Resources -Force
            Import-Module SqlServer -Force


            # Authenticate to Azure
            Connect-AzAccount
            #Write-Host "Request database access token for managed identity"
            #$MI_Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net ).Token

            Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

            # Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
            $name = $Request.Query.Name
            if (-not $name) {
                $name = $Request.Body.Name
            }

            $body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."

            if ($name) {
                $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
            }

            # Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
            Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
                StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
                Body = $body
            })
   ```
3. **host.json**

   ```
            {
              "version": "2.0",
              "managedDependency": {
                "Enabled": true
              },
              "extensionBundle": {
                "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
                "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
              }
            }
   ```
4. **requirements.psd1**

   ```
            @{ 
                'Az' = '2.*'
                'SqlServer' = '22.*'
            }
   ```
5. **Profile.ps1**

   ```
            if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
                Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
                Connect-AzAccount -Identity
            }
   ```
6. **Portal Response:**

   ```
            Connected! You are now viewing logs of Function runs in the current Code + Test panel. To see all the logs for this Function, please go to 'Monitor' from the Function menu.
            2023-12-20T00:29:21Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing the 'Az.Accounts' module. If 'Az.Accounts' is available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency.
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing the 'Az.Resources' module. If 'Az.Resources' is available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency.
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing the 'SqlServer' module. If 'SqlServer' is available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency.
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Warning]   The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Connect-AzAccount' command definition. If this command belongs to a module available on the PowerShell Gallery, add a reference to this module to requirements.psd1. Make sure this module is compatible with PowerShell 7. For more details, see https://aka.ms/functions-powershell-managed-dependency. If the module is installed but you are still getting this error, try to import the module explicitly by invoking Import-Module just before the command that produces the error: this will not fix the issue but will expose the root cause.
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request.
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=02995eda-b227-4971-9fd2-2f9b05f951c1, Duration=133457ms)
            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Error]   ERROR: The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

            Exception             : 
                Type    : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
                Message : The specified module 'Az.Accounts' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
                HResult : -2147024894
            TargetObject          : Az.Accounts
            CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Az.Accounts:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
            FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
            InvocationInfo        : 
                MyCommand        : Import-Module
                ScriptLineNumber : 7
                OffsetInLine     : 1
                HistoryId        : 1
                ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1
                Line             : Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force

                PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1:7 char:1
                                   + Import-Module Az.Accounts -Force
                                   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1
                PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1
                InvocationName   : Import-Module
                CommandOrigin    : Internal
            ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 7
            PipelineIterationInfo : 




            2023-12-20T00:29:22Z   [Error]   ERROR: The specified module 'Az.Resources' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

            Exception             : 
                Type    : System.IO.FileNotFoundException
                Message : The specified module 'Az.Resources' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
                HResult : -2147024894
            TargetObject          : Az.Resources
            CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Az.Resources:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
            FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
            InvocationInfo        : 
                MyCommand        : Import-Module
                ScriptLineNumber : 8
                OffsetInLine     : 1
                HistoryId        : 1
                ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1
                Line             : Import-Module Az.Resources -Force

                PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1:8 char:1
                                   + Import-Module Az.Resources -Force
                                   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1
                PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1
                InvocationName   : Import-Module
                CommandOrigin    : Internal
            ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 8
            PipelineIterationInfo :
   ```

Comment: Did you enable Managed Identity?

Comment: Yes, MI enabled with contributor access on the RG